# Generating correlated variables

Tags: r, parameters, simulation, shapes

I am studying the effects of skewness and kurtosis on the Pearson corrections to bivariate correlations for range restriction.  Currently I am using R and  "rcorrvar" as it should allow me to generate correlated vectors with a specifiable skew and kurtosis.  When I run it as below

```
 rcorrvar(n = 100, k_cont = 2, k_CAT = 2,pois = 2, k_nb = 0,
          method = c("Fleishman", "Polynomial"), means = 0, vars = 1,
          skews = 2,skurts = 4,fifths = NULL, sixths = NULL,
          Six = list(), marginal = list(), support = list(), nrand = 100,
          lam = NULL, size = NULL, prob = NULL, mu = NULL, Sigma = NULL,
          rho = NULL, cstart = NULL, seed = 1234, errorloop = FALSE,
          epsilon = 0.001, maxit = 1000, extra_correct = TRUE)

Error in rcorrvar(n = 100, k_cont = 2, k_CAT = 2, pois = 2, k_nb = 0,  : 
unused arguments (k_CAT = 2, pois = 2)
```

How do I correct these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rcorrvar function you're using is from the SimMultiCorrData package, it appears as though you may have misspelled the two variables - they're supposed to be `k_cat` and `k_pois`.

Please note that R's variables are case-sensitive.